# Ansible: determine exact version of software installed on host

Tags: dictionary, ansible

An alternative question for this post is: how to access nest dict values, specifically in ansible_facts.packages ?

I would like to determine the exact version of software that is installed on a host. If it's lower then my desired, I need to copy over an RPM from local repo and update. I am having a hard time figuring out how to access the nested dict that you get from running package_facts.

I see that package_facts returns data like so:

```
    "msg": {
    ...
    "NessusAgent": [
        {
            "arch": "x86_64", 
            "epoch": null, 
            "name": "NessusAgent", 
            "release": "es7", 
            "source": "rpm", 
            "version": "6.11.1"
        }
    ], 
    ...
```

Here is my playbook trying to store the value for 'version' in a variable ...

```
  - name: check installed software
    package_facts:
      manager: auto

  - name: check installed version
    set_fact:
      sw_ver_installed: "{{ item.value.version }}"
    with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['NessusAgent'] }}"

  - name: debug - sw_ver_installed
    debug:
      var: sw_ver_installed
```

... which fails with this error:

> "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error
>   was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no
>   attribute 'version

I have tried a few variations, which fail with the same or similar errors, or dumps the entire k/v dataset for NessusAgent. I was going off the simple dict examples in Ansible's [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dict.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `with_dict` because your use of `packages["NessusAgent"]` turned that from a `dict[str, list[dict]]` into a `list[dict]`.

Based solely on *that specific result*, you don't need any looping construct, you can just reach into the list and pull out the attribute you want in one shot:

```
set_fact:
   sw_ver_installed: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['NessusAgent']
     | map(attribute='version') | first }}"
```

Or, if you're positive the list will always contain *exactly one* item:

```
set_fact:
   sw_ver_installed: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['NessusAgent'][0].version }}"
```